# Error when using _id as a property type in a Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, schema

I am learning MongoDB and mongoose at the moment. I have a Archive and a User schema in mongoose:

archive.js

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../users/user');

var notesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: User.userId,
    text: String,
    files:[String]
});

var archiveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    priority: String,
    deadline: Date,
    status: String,
    assigned_memnbers: [User.userId],
    notes: [notesSchema],
  });

  archiveSchema.virtual('archiveId').get(function() {
    return this._id;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Archive', archiveSchema);
```

user.js:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    mail: String,
    bio: String,
    password: String
});

userSchema.virtual('userId').get(function() {
    return this._id;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When I run my server i get the error

```js
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `author`, got value "undefined"
```

The the problem comes from `author: User.userId`, but I don't know how to make a reference between the two tables.

For reference, here is what my complete db design more or less looks like:
[image]

Any input on how to solve this problem or improve the overall design is welcome. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're talking about is a reference to other collection:

```
author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
```

and

```
assigned_members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
```

should work fine.

Source: [Mongoose population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.I had imported a module, It was just not exporting from another module. so I have added:

```
exports.genreSchema = genreSchema;
```